# Is there an advantage to using prepared statements in PDO when there are no variables going into the sql query

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Prepared statements are good for protecting against sql injection, but if there are no variables being used in an sql query is there any advantage in using a prepared statement? especially if the query is only going to be used once?

e.g. is there an advantage in using prepare() and execute() over using just query() or is there an advantage to using just query in this case? e.g. performance benfit

Comment: Consistency perhaps? Using common interface layer perhaps?

Comment: i guess, i was also thinking if there were any benefits to using query in this case. i have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Which DBMS make and model? Oracle and SQL server have a precompilation thing. MySQL, not.

Comment: @O.Jones PHP doesn't have a benefit of using precompiled queries, I believe.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Could be. But still, Oracle looks up prepared queries in a compilation cache by hashing the text of the query. If you're hammering the server with a lot of the same query, it can help. But the use case for hammering a server with a prepared but not parameterized query escapes me. It's not going to help much.

Comment: @O.Jones well at least mysql have a query cache, so If you're hammering the server with a lot of the same query, the result will be given to you immediately, without even execution, let alone compling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no benefit. Although the difference is negligible, you can always write a *function* to implement even such a minor optimization:

```
class MyPDO extends PDO
{
    public function run($sql, $args = NULL)
    {
        if (!$args)
        {
            return $this->query($sql);
        }
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

now you've got PDO that can decide whether to run a prepared statement or not:

```
$pdo   = new MyPDO(...);
$count = $pdo->run("SELECT count(*) FROM t")->fetchColumn(); // no prepare
$user  = $pdo->run("SELECT * FROM t WHERE id=?",[$id])->fetch(); // prepare
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use query only once then it will be **no difference** except that prepared statement will create execution metaplan (but it is not noticeable performance difference). 
If you use query with prepared statements multiple times with different parameters you get small performance improvement, because statement is compiled only once in server side and then you can pass different parameters multiple times. Query will be compiled only when you use real prepared statements if you use emulated prepared statements then it won't be compiled and besides sql injecion protection it will be no difference in performance.

Comment: so is there no benefit to using query over prepare and execute, e.g. less load on the server (compiling the query)

Comment: if you will use sql only once without parameters just use query, i have edited my answer with metaplan

Comment: different parameters?  The OP says that variables are not being used.

Comment: I just explained what happens when there is parameters.